# Command to change brightness level in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 18.04, 17.10, brightness, wayland

What are the commands to increase and decrease the brightness level in Ubuntu 17.10? It seems like `xrandr` and `xbacklight` does not work with Wayland.

I can still write the value I want on */sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness*

for example:

```
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<<500
```

But I'm trying to find the actual commands and create two keyboard shortcuts with it to increase or decrease my brightness level.

Answer (score 1):

The utility "brightnessctl" is in the software repositories (as of Ubuntu 18.04 at least) and works with wayland.

Comment: Yes, brightnessctl is working in Wayland but it's not ideal for keyboard shortcut as you should run this program with root privileges. Any workaround on that?